# passing data back to activity from service

Tags: android, service, android-activity, intentservice

In order to pass data back to activity from service, I came to know about **ResultReceiver**, **broadcast/local broadcasts** and **binded service**. However I am confused about this approach: If we simply call activity static public funcion to pass something back, what are the pros and cons of this approach. Say I have activity:

```
public interface ListenerInterface {

    void DataExchange(String data);


}
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ListenerInterface{

    private static MainActivity instance;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        instance=this;

        Intent i=new Intent();
        i.setClass(this, MyService.class);
        startService(i);
    }

    public static MainActivity getInstance(){
        if(instance!=null)
            return instance;

        return null;
    }

    @Override
public void DataExchange(String data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("sohail","data received="+data);
}

}
```

and an IntentService:

```
public class MyService extends IntentService{

    MainActivity obj;
    public MyService() {
        super("MyService");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        MainActivity.getInstance().DataExchange("Service Data");
    }

}
```

Comment: Never, ever, ever create public / static methods or member variables in an `Activity` which you intend to be accessed by other application components - it won't work and it's not how it's meant to work. Please read http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html An `Activity` is a 'special case' class and is meant to be stand-alone. Use a `ResultReceiver`, bind to a `Service` or use a `BroadcastReceiver` by all means but NEVER assume you can access a public / static member of an `Activity`.

Comment: `private static MainActivity instance;` this will cause memory leaks in your application

Comment: Thanks everybody, I was using all those approaches discussed above but get confused after knowing this approach in very famous VoIP applicaion [linphone](http://www.linphone.org). Much clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cons:

- there can be multiple instances of an activity, with your approach only the one created last will get the result.
- it may or may not be visible/usable when the result is delivered.
- your service will be directly depending on your UI(Activity).

A better approach would be to have the activity implement some interface (say `DataHandler`) and not couple it directly to the service. Additionally, to make sure you only receive data when you can actually do something with it, have the activity register itself as a handler `onStart()` and unregister `onStop()`.

Comment: `getInstance()` on an activity simply doesn't fly :) The lifecycle is managed by the platform, so you have to run with that or your app will crash and burn. Why do you insist on doing it this way?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answers Elenkov, I was using all those approaches discussed above but get confused after knowing this approach in very famous VoIP applicaion [linphone](http://www.linphone.org/eng/download/packages/).